# How to count the number of different sequences possible?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Lets consider all matrices with N rows (numbered 1 through N) and M columns (numbered 1 through M) containing only integers between 0 and K−1 (inclusive). For each such matrix A, let's form a sequence L[1],L[2],…,L[N+M]

For each 'i' (1≤i≤N), L[i] is the maximum of all elements in the i-th row of A.
For each 'i' (1≤i≤M), L[N+i] is the maximum of all elements in the i-th column of A.
Find the number of different sequences formed this way.
My approach is simple brute-force.

Example:- N=2;M=2;K=2

Answer:-10

All 16 different possible matrices are as follows:-

[0, 0]

[0, 0] = (0, 0, 0, 0) (sequence generated)

[0, 0]

[0, 1] = (0, 1, 0, 1)

[0, 0]

[1, 0] = (0, 1, 1, 0)

[0, 1]

[0, 0] = (1, 0, 0, 1)

[1, 0]

[0, 0] = (1, 0, 1, 0)

[1, 0]

[1, 0] = (1, 1, 1, 0)

[1, 1]

[0, 0] = (1, 0, 1, 1)

[0, 0]

[1, 1] = (0, 1, 1, 1)

[0, 1]

[0, 1] = (1, 1, 0, 1)

[1, 0]

[0, 0] = (1, 0, 1, 0)

[0, 1]

[1, 0] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

[1, 1]

[1, 0] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

[1, 1]

[0, 1] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

[1, 1]

[0, 1] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

[1, 0]

[1, 1] = (1, 1, 1, 1)

[1, 1]

[1, 1]  =  (1, 1, 1, 1)

Comment: Matrix `[1,0];[0,0]` seems duplicated in the example (the 5th and 10th matrices).

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a series of hints:

For a given matrix A and the associated L, find a relation between the maximum of `L[1],...,L[N]` (the row maximums) and the maximum of `L[N+1],...,L[N+M]` (the column maximums).

Next, try to prove that any L-sequence with integers from 0 to K-1 that fulfills these conditions can actually be obtained by some matrix A.

Finally, count those sequences.

Comment: Hi @Ingix, good to see you are helping. :) but don't you think writing a little elaborated but not much answer would make more sense when you are actually writing answer of SO.

Comment: @psyco The main 'problem' is that the question is a math question. As for many finite prolems, you can do a brute force search with code, but if K.M,N get 'large', you get a really big search space. M=N=K=5 already is almost 3*10^17 matrices. I wanted to write a more direct solution, but then realized that MathJax is not available on this sub-board, which is a big distractor to create a readable solution. I'm not sure if it is possible to migrate the question to math.stackexchange, if it's reposted there I'll write up a solution.

Comment: Hi @lngix ; here is the same question on math stack exchange asked by me so you can answer:- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260717/how-to-count-the-number-of-different-sequences-possible?noredirect=1#comment6705080_3260717

Comment: Thanks, will do. Today hopefully, maybe tomorrow. Wrting an in-depth math answer can take time (for me, at least).

Comment: It looks like the answer is already there! Moral: If you have math questions, post them on the math board, you'll get answers by many more people, not just me ;-)

Comment: @Ingix, nope your help is needed the most because that is just a partial answer(summation formula). I need your help to calculate its closed form

Comment: @Firexsecred I would have ended at the same formula; I don't see a way to make it easier. Maybe someone else does in the new question you formulated.